# Bringing prescribed opioids into the USA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

What are the documents required to enter the USA with prescribed opioid for back issues?

My Dutch friend has a doctor's prescription in English and has been told she must go to the US embassy in The Hague to get the prescription stamped. Then she must go to a court to have it validated. Are there any other requirements?

Answer (score 8):

The [CBP webpage on entering the US with prescription medication](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1160?language=en_US) says:

> Prescription medications should be in their original containers with the doctor's prescription printed on the container. It is advised that you travel with no more than personal use quantities, a rule of thumb is no more than a 90 day supply.  If your medications or devices are not in their original containers, you must have a copy of your prescription with you or a letter from your doctor.  A valid prescription or doctors note is required on all medication entering the United States.

Thus: what's required is that the medicine be prescribed.

Using the original container, with current and correct information on the label, is preferred. In the alternative, a copy of the current prescription or a doctor's letter should be carried. It is suggested that no more than a 90-day supply be carried.

There is no need for stamping (whatever that is) or going to court.

Comment: "Stamping" probably refers to getting an apostille, but it sounds like that's not necessary

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but the traveler should additionally check if the drug they are planning to bring is on the [controlled substances list](https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/orangebook/c_cs_alpha.pdf) and be prepared to comply with [21 CFR 1301.26](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-21/chapter-II/part-1301/subject-group-ECFRa5bd18e3d01cd02/section-1301.26) if so; in particular, schedule I drugs are not allowed at all, and a declaration must be made at customs. I still can not find any evidence of this alleged stamping requirement.

Comment: The word opioid suggests that this might be a case of a substance that a doctor in the Netherlands can legally prescribe as a medicine but the same substance just counts as an illegal drug in the US with no medical use. I don't know whether this is actually the case but I also don't know whether this answer would still be correct in this case.